# armature weights not working

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, dupli-groups

This is the first time I had this problem. When I did automatic weights I had to redo the hands since in I had to clean up the vertices and the fingers were stuck together.  One the left hand I had no problems but the right hand I duplicated and mirrored and simply attached the hand.  I attached the bones and parented them, but when I move the bones it is moving other fingers not attached to the current bone.  I checked the vertex groups and they are .[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try selecting all the vertex points you want to represent the right hand, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>  to invert the selection to the rest of the mesh, and press *Remove* to remove them from the right-hand vertex group, while the right-hand vertex group is selected and highlighted of course.